# Concatenate certain rows into a cell ignoring duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-forms

I have a google form and I would like to sort it's responses in a separate sheet on google sheets. The results of the form look sort of like this.

```
Id    Job
1     Shelving, Sorting
2     Sorting
1     Cleaning, Shelving
3     Customer Service
2     Shelving, Sorting
```

which I would like to format into

```
Id    Jobs
1     Cleaning, Shelving, Sorting
2     Shelving, Sorting
3     Customer Service
```

Is there a formula I can use to accomplish this, noting that it ignores duplicates and groups the different ids? Ordering of the jobs does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XqT2FWPzrG3hA6rGu3i-UaNOvaJ-CfhdO6gARfyaNpQ/edit?usp=sharing).

The code is like:

```
=unique(transpose(split(join(", ",filter(B1:B10,A1:A10=1)),", ")))
```

where

- `filter(B1:B10,A1:A10=1)` gives you all the B values where A = 1
- `join(",", filter(...))` joins the list with the ", " separator (e.g. "apple, orange" and "kiwi" becomes "apple, orange, kiwi"
- `split(join(...))` [splits](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136/?hl=en&authuser=0) the list into an array (e.g. back to [apple, orange, kiwi]
- `transpose(split(...))` [converts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262/?hl=en&authuser=0) the horizontal list to vertical list
- `unique(transpose(...))` gives you the [unique](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198/?hl=en&authuser=0) values (`unique()` only works with vertical list)

After this, you need to `transpose` then `join` the list

Note you must keep the separator consistent (e.g. always "," or ", ")

Comment: Works perfectly after transposing it and joining it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is Apps Script code instead of a function.  To use it, you will need to use the Tools menu, and open the script editor.  Then select the function name from the drop down list, and then click the "Run" button.

To use this code, you need to have a source and a destination sheet.  You will need to change the sheet names in the code to your sheet names.  In this code, the source sheet is named 'Data'.  You will need to change that to the name of your source sheet.  In this code, the destination sheet is named 'Output', and is at the bottom of the code.  This code gets data starting in row two, and writes the output data starting in row two.  I tested it with your values and it works.

```
function concatCellData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Data');

  var colOneData = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var colTwoData = sh.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

  var newData = [],
      newDataColOne = [],
      colOneValue,
      existInNewData = false,
      colB_One,
      colB_Two,
      dataPosition,
      thisValue,
      combinedArrays = [],
      arrayTemp = [];

  for (var i=0;i<colOneData.length;i+=1) {
    colOneValue = colOneData[i][0];
    dataPosition = newDataColOne.indexOf(colOneValue);
    existInNewData = dataPosition !== -1;

    if (!existInNewData) {//If it doesn't exist in the new data, just write the values
      newDataColOne.push(colOneValue);
      newData.push([colOneValue, colTwoData[i][0]]);
      continue;
    };

    colB_One = [];
    colB_Two = [];
    combinedArrays = []
    arrayTemp = [];

    colB_One = colTwoData[i][0].split(",");
    colB_Two = newData[dataPosition][1];
    colB_Two = colB_Two.split(",");

    var combinedArrays = colB_One.concat(colB_Two);

    //Get unique values
    for (var j=0;j<combinedArrays.length;j+=1) {
      thisValue = combinedArrays[j].trim();
      if (arrayTemp.indexOf(thisValue) === -1) {
        arrayTemp.push(thisValue);
      };
    };

    newData[dataPosition] = [colOneValue, arrayTemp.toString()]; //Overwrite existing data

  };

  ss.getSheetByName('Output').getRange(2, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
};
```