# Google Sheet Concatenate certain cells contents of selected rows

Tags: concatenation

I have a table with two columns.  Column A includes dates and column B contains simple text.  The date column has duplicates.  What I want to have is concatenate the contents of column B cells for identical dates. Basically, similar to running a query and grouping on the date column with an aggregate function like sum() on column B; but there is no aggregate function for text.  The solution needs to be for a dynamic list, as the input is made via a google form by the users.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110455/concatenate-certain-rows-into-a-cell-ignoring-duplicates) offers a solution but you have to copy and paste the rows.

Many thanks

Sabba

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895935/google-sheets-function-to-group-and-concat-rows) which worked perfectly for me.